# Related Links Blender Plugin for Wordpress

Tags: database, wordpress, post

I have a problem with plugin Related Links Blender. It's the best of all related links plugins, really - it's simply edited and everything, but if you add some related links to post, you can't change it any more.

I mean:
In administration (below post editor) it's deleted, changed, everything what you want and what you clicked. But in post it's still showing just your first choice.

Here is the code of part about deleting:

```
    function deleting_a_link() {
    $link_info = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['link_info']), true);
    $nonce_check=check_ajax_referer('my_nonce','nonce',false);

    if ( ! current_user_can('edit_post',$link_info['post_id']) )  {
        echo json_encode(array('success'=>false,'response'=>'You don\'t have permission to make this change.'));
    } else if (!$nonce_check) {
        echo json_encode(array('success'=>false,'response'=>'Illegal connection.'));
    } else {
        $current_links=get_post_meta(intval($link_info['post_id']),'related_links_blender_links',true);

        if (is_array($current_links)) { //$current_links is false if empty
            unset($current_links[$link_info['link_no']]);
            update_post_meta(intval($link_info['post_id']),'related_links_blender_links',$current_links);
            $this->smush_the_links($link_info['post_id'],$current_links);
            echo json_encode(array('success'=>true,'link_no'=>$link_info['link_no']));
        } else {
            echo json_encode(array('success'=>false));
        }
    }
    die();
}
```

I can't see mistake. Do know anyone, what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Once Deactivate your Plugin and after that Re-Active your Plugin it Solves Your Problem.

Comment: No, problem is still here. I tried it and now I'm trying it again - and nothing is changed. In database is still what I don't want. It's really bad for me.

Comment: Here is all of this code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367761/related-links-blender-plugin-wp-doesnt-work-well